# удаление строк в БД SQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, drupal

есть БД работающего сайта на друпал 7
в последнее время появились записи при редактировании товаров

```
a:12:{s:8:"cell_0_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_0_1";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_1_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_1_1";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_2_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_2_1";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_3_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_3_1";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:7:"rebuild";a:3:{s:10:"count_cols";i:2;s:10:"count_rows";i:4;s:7:"rebuild";s:37:"Перестроить таблицу";}s:6:"import";a:2:{s:4:"file";s:0:"";s:6:"import";s:22:"Загрузить CSV";}s:5:"paste";a:3:{s:15:"paste_delimiter";s:0:"";s:4:"data";s:0:"";s:12:"paste_import";s:16:"Import & Rebuild";}}
```

появляется такое в карточке товара в виде пустых таблиц
добавляется в таблицу field_data_field_spec, где находятся характеристики и комплектация товара (2 типа таблиц)

кто подскажет SQL запрос чтобы удалить за раз из таблицы все такие дублирующиеся строки?
ну и вдогонку (если решится - это будет чудо) - может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой на друпале? с генерацией пустых таблиц

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `entity_type` , `bundle` , `deleted` , `entity_id` , `revision_id` , `language` , `delta` , `field_spec_value` , `field_spec_format`
FROM `field_data_field_spec`
WHERE `field_spec_value` = 'a:12:{s:8:"cell_0_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_0_1";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_1_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_1_1";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_2_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_2_1";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_3_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_3_1";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:7:"rebuild";a:3:{s:10:"count_cols";i:2;s:10:"count_rows";i:4;s:7:"rebuild";s:37:"Перестроить таблицу";}s:6:"import";a:2:{s:4:"file";s:0:"";s:6:"import";s:22:"Загрузить CSV";}s:5:"paste";a:3:{s:15:"paste_delimiter";s:0:"";s:4:"data";s:0:"";s:12:"paste_import";s:16:"Import & Rebuild";}}'
```

все пустые таблицы выдало!

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM field_data_field_spec WHERE field_spec_value='a:12:{s:8:"cell_0_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_0_1";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_1_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_1_1";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_2_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_2_1";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_3_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_3_1";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:7:"rebuild";a:3:{s:10:"count_cols";i:2;s:10:"count_rows";i:4;s:7:"rebuild";s:37:"Перестроить таблицу";}s:6:"import";a:2:{s:4:"file";s:0:"";s:6:"import";s:22:"Загрузить CSV";}s:5:"paste";a:3:{s:15:"paste_delimiter";s:0:"";s:4:"data";s:0:"";s:12:"paste_import";s:16:"Import & Rebuild";}}'
```

или
более правильно для такого как я 
сперва селектом пройтись
и потом выделить все

```
SELECT FROM field_data_field_spec WHERE field_spec_value='a:12:{s:8:"cell_0_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_0_1";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_1_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_1_1";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_2_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_2_1";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_3_0";s:0:"";s:8:"cell_3_1";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:7:"rebuild";a:3:{s:10:"count_cols";i:2;s:10:"count_rows";i:4;s:7:"rebuild";s:37:"Перестроить таблицу";}s:6:"import";a:2:{s:4:"file";s:0:"";s:6:"import";s:22:"Загрузить CSV";}s:5:"paste";a:3:{s:15:"paste_delimiter";s:0:"";s:4:"data";s:0:"";s:12:"paste_import";s:16:"Import & Rebuild";}}'
```

поправьте кто сведущий в этом!